# Centering navbar items correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning HTML, CSS and Javacript. I'm making a restaurant website and currently working on the navbar.

I have 4 topics of the navbar (Home, menu, review and about us) and a button for contact.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gastronomy Galaxy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <button id="contact">Contact</button>
            </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #A78F69;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #A78F69; 
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

nav a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#contact {
    
}
```

I tried to centered the 4 topics but it seems that the button (aligned at the right side of the navbar) is interfiring with the centering of the 4 topics, because it seems a little off the center of the full width of the monitor...

I already saw some videos but it always has 3 main parts (An image, the topics, and the button), but I only have 2 (the topics and the button)...
Can somebody help me? Thanks! (By the way, sorry if my theres is some grammar errors)

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution is to make margin-left instead of margin-right in nav li, also remove padding:0 in nav ul.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding justify-content: center and flex-grow: 1; to the 'nav ul' element.

It should look like below,

[image]